# Как вытащить из словаря список(в значении)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = {'tunnels': [{'name': 'command_line', 'uri': '/api/tunnels/command_line', 'publi
c_url': 'tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:16961', 'proto': 'tcp', 'config': {'addr': 'localh
ost:4040', 'inspect': False}, 'metrics': {'conns': {'count': 0, 'gauge': 0, 'rat
e1': 0, 'rate5': 0, 'rate15': 0, 'p50': 0, 'p90': 0, 'p95': 0, 'p99': 0}, 'http'
: {'count': 0, 'rate1': 0, 'rate5': 0, 'rate15': 0, 'p50': 0, 'p90': 0, 'p95': 0
, 'p99': 0}}}], 'uri': '/api/tunnels'}

for x in a['tunnels']['name']:
    print (x)
```

Ловлю ошибку `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`
Как вытащить значение `public_url` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for x in a['tunnels']:
    print(x['public_url'])
```

или

```
print(a['tunnels'][0]['public_url'])
```